# Is it possible to convert a pdf chart to excel using Python?

Tags: python, excel, pdf

Firstly, I can't seem to find any code on this so far. Plenty on convert excel data to pdf but not the other way round. So apologies for the lack of code. Also, I'm not a pdf expert, so may be this is impossible.

My question is this, is it possible to take a pdf which includes a graph and convert that graph back to excel. Specifically the data. So take the example from this chart below which is included in the factsheet of the BlackRock UK fund. Can this be converted back in to excel using Python? Data points matching dates i.e. a time series.

[image]

https://www.blackrock.com/uk/literature/fact-sheet/blackrock-uk-fund-class-a-accu-gbp-factsheet-gb0005773774-gb-en-individual.pdf

Comment: If that chart is an image in the PDF then there is no way that you can programmatically convert it to Excel. The only possibility, is if the PDF files stores it as a table of values.

Comment: I'm not going to deny, it's a bit of a long shot.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the internals PDF, the graphic you have selected is not an image, but rather a series of PDF draw commands.  Technically, the information is there, but it is stored in an abstract context, making the usability very low without a lot of work.  Here is a peek:

```
import pikepdf

doc = pikepdf.Pdf.open('blackrock.pdf')
page = doc.pages[1]
print(page.resources.XObject.Xf5.read_bytes().decode()[:217])
```

This gives the following output, which is a sequence of commands to the PDF renderer for drawing graphics.

```
q
0 151.2 m
0 0 l
542.23 0 l
542.23 151.2 l
h
W
n
1 w
2 J
0 j
10 M
[]0 d
q
0 151.2 m
541.51 151.2 l
541.51 0.19901 l
0 0.19901 l
0 151.2 l
h
W
n
0.86286 w
1 j
0.75294 0.75294 0.75294 RG
38.93 61.4 m
534.3 61.4 l
S
Q
q
```

Looking at them, we start with:

- q - save the current graphics state
- (x, y) m - move the cursor to location x, y to begin a new subpath drawing
- (x, y) l - append a straight line from the current location to (x, y)
- (x, y) l - same thing
- (x, y) l - same thing, appears to be drawing the outer box
- h - close the subpath
- W - modify the current clipping path
- n - end the path object
- w, J, j, M, d - set the line width, cap style, join style, mitre, and dash
- q - save the graphics state
- etc...
- (r, g, b) RG - change the color to r,g,b
- S - paint the stroke path
- Q - restore the latest graphics state from the graphics stack

By parsing this information, you can extract the relative motion of each of the lines in the image as an array of sub-pixel movements.  However, you will still need to get the end value of each line to scale the movement to the price.

Is it possible?  Yes.  Is it worth your time?  Well, that is up to you.